# Intel xdk, record a video from the camera in background

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I made some search around but I couldn't find an answer for that.
I would like to capture a video using intel xdk but i don't want to launch a video recording App on the foreground, i want it to:

- run in the background
- start recording immediately
- stop recording after a given amount of time or by a function call

I tried to use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture with `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1, duration:10});` but it opens the camera app and then is up to the user to start the recording (tried with a moto g)

any suggestion/code sample are welcome :)

Comment: in your case its better to go native, its just to specific.

Comment: A quick google serach didn't reveal any plugins that do what you want.  Rather than go completely native, it's also possible to write a cordova plugin that does what you want, then just that part would be native, the rest of your app would be web based.

Comment: at the moment make my own plugin looks the only viable option. For android there is already something here https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core